React Player Cancel on unmount
The main problem is that I have some players at first page, and when i change to the other page, where only one player is present, it still requesting the data for other players, from previous pages, so it appears to wait for a long time before desired video will be loading into player.
I have already tried to cancel it using window.performance, but still had no result
